# Why does response code return a different code?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, httpresponsemessage

In a WebAPI app, I throw and exception, which is caught. I then do this:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
  return Request.CreateResponse(HttpstatusCode.BadRequest);
}
```

On the caller side, the message is statuscode 400 as expected.

When I do this instead:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
  return Request.CreateResponse(HttpstatusCode.BadRequest, myFile);
}
```

where `myFile` is an `HttpPostedFile`, the caller gets a 500 code.
 `HttpstatusCode.BadRequest` == 400. How is the caller getting a 500 in the 2nd scenario?

Comment: The myFile variable is of type HttpPostedFile? Try this `new StreamReader(myFile.InputStream).ReadToEnd();`, instead of just passing in myFile as the second argument.

Comment: That line executes but of course the content is jibberish.

Comment: Can you post the actual file and the gibberish response?

Comment: I can't post the actual file since it has sensitive info. I'm sure the response is just binary.

Comment: A guess: a 400 return code doesn't allow for "content", so you get an exception - which is reported as a 500 status.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of CreateResponse:
Use:=>
Only assign Response.StatusCode=StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;
this will automatically return status 400.
**OR**
Return following object as
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest);

Comment: Where is "Only assign"?

Comment: In controller's method

Comment: just assign the values to Response.Statuscode property.